# Composite PK null id generated

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, jakarta-ee

Spring Boot: 2.0.2

Hibernate Core: 5.2.17

dialect: SQLServer2012Dialect

When trying to save DistributionActivities entity using JpaRepository save() method the operation fails with the following message:

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated
>   for:class DistributionActivitiesEmails

Parent Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DistributionActivities")
public class DistributionActivities implements Serializable 
{   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    @Column(name ="ActivityID")
    private Long activityID;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name="activityID", referencedColumnName="activityID")
    private Set<DistributionActivitiesEmails> distributionActivitiesEmails;
}
```

Child Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DistributionActivitiesEmails ")
public class DistributionActivitiesEmails implements Serializable 
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private DistributionActivitiesEmailsId id;

    @Length(max = 50)
    private String EmailAdress;
}
```

Composite PK :

```
@Embeddable
public class DistributionActivitiesEmailsId implements Serializable 
{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ActivityID")
    private DistributionActivities distributionActivities;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    @Column(name ="ActivityEmailID")
    private Long activityEmailID;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @EmbeddedId javadoc, Relationship mappings defined within an embedded id class are not supported.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way a Composite PK can have both parent id and a generated id ?

Comment: What does it mean “populate the parent object variable in the child class too in order to carry forward the primary key to the child class”
Do I have to save the entities separately ? first parent entity DistributionActivities and then child entities DistributionActivitiesEmails ?

Comment: In  DistributionActivitiesEmails take DistributionActivities(parent) object OneToOne relation.

Refer This also : https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: What about GeneratedValue ? if I understood correctly we cannot use it inside composite key. Any alternatives ?